# A certain Complex line integral

Tags: complex-analysis, line-integrals

In evaluating the line integral of $\frac{dz}{z-2}$ around the circle $|z-1|=5$ , and also around the square with vertices $3+3i ,3-3i,-3+3i,-3-3i$, I obtain zero in both cases however my textbook gives $2\pi i$ in both cases. Am I correct here?

(The usual parametrizations obviously work here.....)

Comment: I would trust your book  in this case. Can you show what you have done? (be careful about the multi-valuedness of the logarithm function!)

Comment: A theorem in Complex Analysis, which you've probably come across, gives the answer $2\pi i$. You don't need to parametrize the contour.

Comment: Your book is correct. When you integrate along the circle or square, the anti-derivative $\log(z-2)$ picks up a difference $2\pi i$ across the two end points of any parametrization you pick. So the answer is $2\pi i$.

Comment: The parametrization z=5exp(it)+1  gives  ln {5exp(it)-1} from 2 (pi) to 0 which is zero.....

Comment: $\log(5e^{it} - 1) = \log 5 + it + \log(1 - \frac15 e^{-it})$. Notice $|\frac15 e^{-it}| < 1$, when you move $t$ from $0$ to $2\pi$, the piece $\log(1-\frac15 e^{-it})$ return to its starting point. However,  the $it$ term pick up a $2\pi i$ change.

Comment: Thanks achille hui for your answer , but do we use this trick every time we have a log in our answer?? I do not get 2(pi) i for the square too , how do we get the answer in that case??

Answer (score 0):

Integral is sum of  residues at poles multiplied by $2\pi i$ , here $z=2$ is a simple pole and residue at $z=2$ is 1.